# Collect all "minimum" solutions from a predicate

Tags: prolog, backtracking, aggregates, prolog-setof, meta-predicate

Given the following facts in a database:

```
foo(a, 3).
foo(b, 2).
foo(c, 4).
foo(d, 3).
foo(e, 2).
foo(f, 6).
foo(g, 3).
foo(h, 2).
```

I want to collect all first arguments that have the smallest second argument, plus the value of the second argument. First try:

```
find_min_1(Min, As) :-
    setof(B-A, foo(A, B), [Min-_|_]),
    findall(A, foo(A, Min), As).

?- find_min_1(Min, As).
Min = 2,
As = [b, e, h].
```

Instead of `setof/3`, I could use `aggregate/3`:

```
find_min_2(Min, As) :-
    aggregate(min(B), A^foo(A, B), Min),
    findall(A, foo(A, Min), As).

?- find_min_2(Min, As).
Min = 2,
As = [b, e, h].
```

**NB**

This only gives the same results if I am looking for the minimum of a **number**. If an arithmetic expression in involved, the results might be different. If a non-number is involved, `aggregate(min(...), ...)` will throw an error!

Or, instead, I can use the full key-sorted list:

```
find_min_3(Min, As) :-
    setof(B-A, foo(A, B), [Min-First|Rest]),
    min_prefix([Min-First|Rest], Min, As).

min_prefix([Min-First|Rest], Min, [First|As]) :-
    !,
    min_prefix(Rest, Min, As).
min_prefix(_, _, []).

?- find_min_3(Min, As).
Min = 2,
As = [b, e, h].
```

Finally, to the question(s):

- Can I do this directly with library(aggregate)? It feels like it should be possible....
- Or is there a predicate like [`std::partition_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point) from the C++ standard library?
- Or is there some easier way to do this?

EDIT:

To be more descriptive. Say there was a (library) predicate `partition_point/4`:

```
partition_point(Pred_1, List, Before, After) :-
    partition_point_1(List, Pred_1, Before, After).

partition_point_1([], _, [], []).
partition_point_1([H|T], Pred_1, Before, After) :-
    (   call(Pred_1, H)
    ->  Before = [H|B],
        partition_point_1(T, Pred_1, B, After)
    ;   Before = [],
        After = [H|T]
    ).
```

(I don't like the name but we can live with it for now)

Then:

```
find_min_4(Min, As) :-
    setof(B-A, foo(A, B), [Min-X|Rest]),
    partition_point(is_min(Min), [Min-X|Rest], Min_pairs, _),
    pairs_values(Min_pairs, As).

is_min(Min, Min-_).

?- find_min_4(Min, As).
Min = 2,
As = [b, e, h].
```

Comment: what does "do this directly" mean, and how does C++ come into play?

Comment: @ScottHunter "Directly" means that there is a way to invoke one of the library predicates in library(aggregate) to do this, but I am too thick to figure it out. The C++ is mentioned, because the linked algorithm does something very similar to my `min_prefix/3`, but in a more general fashion.

Comment: @ScottHunter See my edit for the rationale behind mentioning `partition_point`.

Comment: @DanielLyons: It would we very interesting to see the corresponding SQL-query. After all SQL-queries are often - well not compact - but at least free of unnecessary notions. I will put a bounty for this.

Comment: @Boris: Thanks! BTW, I have 2 bounties open that are realistic to get (and a third just to thank someone). In particular the one ending tomorrow!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`library(pairs)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs) and [`sort/4`], this can be simply written as:

```
?- bagof(B-A, foo(A, B), Ps),
   sort(1, @=<, Ps, Ss), % or keysort(Ps, Ss)
   group_pairs_by_key(Ss, [Min-As|_]).
Min = 2,
As = [b, e, h].
```

This call to `sort/4` can be replaced with `keysort/2`, but with `sort/4` one can also find for example the first arguments associated with the largest second argument: just use `@>=` as the second argument.

This solution is probably not as time and space efficient as the other ones, but may be easier to grok.

But there is another way to do it altogether:

```
?- bagof(A, ( foo(A, Min), \+ ( foo(_, Y), Y @< Min ) ), As).
Min = 2,
As = [b, e, h].
```

Answer (score 4):

> What is the idiomatic approach to this class of problems?
>
> Is there a way to simplify the problem?

Many of the following remarks could be added to many programs here on SO.

### Imperative names

Every time, you write an imperative name for something that is a relation you will reduce your understanding of relations. Not much, just a little bit. Many common Prolog idioms like `append/3` do not set a good example. Think of `append(As,As,AsAs)`. The first argument of `find_min(Min, As)` is the minimum. So `minimum_with_nodes/2` might be a better name.

### `findall/3`

Do not use `findall/3` unless the uses are rigorously checked, essentially everything must be ground. In your case it happens to work. But once you generalize `foo/2` a bit, you will lose. And that is frequently a problem: You write a tiny program ; and it seems to work.
Once you move to bigger ones, the same approach no longer works. `findall/3` is (compared to `setof/3`) like a bull in a china shop smashing the fine fabric of shared variables and quantification. Another problem is that accidental failure does not lead to failure of `findall/3` which often leads to bizarre, hard to imagine corner cases.

### Untestable, too specific program

Another problem is somewhat related to `findall/3`, too. Your program is so specific, that it is quite improbable that you will ever test it. And marginal changes will invalidate your tests. So you will soon give up to perform testing. Let's see what is specific: Primarily the `foo/2` relation. Yes, only an example. Think of how to set up a test configuration where `foo/2` may change. After each change (writing a new file) you will have to reload the program. This is so complex, chances are you will never do it. I presume you do not have a test harness for that. Plunit for one, does not cover such testing.
As a rule of thumb: If you cannot test a predicate on the top level you never will. Consider instead

> `minimum_with(Rel_2, Min, Els)`

With such a relation, you can now have a generalized `xfoo/3` with an additional parameter, say:

```
xfoo(o, A,B) :-
   foo(A,B).
xfoo(n, A,B) :-
   newfoo(A,B).
```

and you most naturally get two answers for `minimum_with(xfoo(X), Min, Els)`. Would you have used `findall/3` instead of `setof/3` you already would have serious problems. Or just in general: `minmum_with(\A^B^member(A-B, [x-10,y-20]), Min, Els)`. So you can play around on the top level and produce lots of interesting test cases.

### Unchecked border cases

Your version 3 is clearly my preferred approach, however there are still some parts that can be improved. In particular, if there are answers that contain variables as a minimum. These should be checked.

And certainly, also `setof/3` has its limits. And ideally you would test them. Answers should not contain constraints, in particular not in the relevant variables. This shows how `setof/3` itself has certain limits. After the pioneering phase, SICStus produced many errors for constraints in such cases (mid 1990s), later changed to consequently ignoring constraints in built-ins that cannot handle them. SWI on the other hand does entirely undefined things here. Sometimes things are copied, sometimes not. As an example take:
`setof(A, ( A in 1..3 ; A in 3..5 ), _)` and `setof(t, ( A in 1..3 ; A in 3.. 5 ), _)`.

By wrapping the goal this can be avoided.

```
call_unconstrained(Goal_0) :-
   call_residue_vars(Goal_0, Vs),
   ( Vs = [] -> true ; throw(error(representation_error(constraint),_)) ).
```

Beware, however, that SWI has spurious constraints:

```
?- call_residue_vars(all_different([]), Xs).
   Xs = [_A].
```

Not clear if this is a feature in the meantime. It has been there since the introduction of `call_residue_vars/2` about 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that library(aggregate) covers your use case. aggregate(min) allows for *one* witness:

> min(Expr, Witness)
>       A term min(Min, Witness), where Min is the minimal version of Expr over all solutions, and Witness is any other template applied to solutions that produced Min. If multiple solutions provide the same minimum, Witness corresponds to the first solution.

Some time ago, I wrote a small 'library', [lag.pl](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/blob/master/lag.pl), with predicates to aggregate with low overhead - hence the name (LAG = Linear AGgregate). I've added a snippet, that handles your use case:

```
integrate(min_list_associated, Goal, Min-Ws) :-
    State = term(_, [], _),
    forall(call(Goal, V, W),    % W stands for witness
        (    arg(1, State, C),  % C is current min
             arg(2, State, CW), % CW are current min witnesses
             (   ( var(C) ; V @< C )
             ->  U = V, Ws = [W]
             ;   U = C,
                 (   C == V
                 ->  Ws = [W|CW]
                 ;   Ws = CW
                 )
             ),
             nb_setarg(1, State, U),
             nb_setarg(2, State, Ws)
        )),
    arg(1, State, Min), arg(2, State, Ws).
```

It's a simple minded extension of integrate(min)...
The comparison method it's surely questionable (it uses less general operator for equality), could be worth to adopt instead a conventional call like that adopted for [predsort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3)/3. Efficiency wise, still better would be to encode the comparison method as option in the 'function selector' (min_list_associated in this case)

*edit* thanks @false and @Boris for correcting the bug relative to the state representation. Calling `nb_setarg(2, State, Ws)` actually changes the term' shape, when `State = (_,[],_)` was used. Will update the github repo accordingly...

Comment: I am not sure I can actually tell `integrate/3` what my Expression and Witness are, or am I missing something? (I need to switch the order of `V` and `W` in `call(Goal, V, W)`, otherwise it does not do what I initially was going for? Also, it inadvertently reverses the order of the solutions.) Otherwise, yes, this is the straight-forward implementation of what I am trying to achieve. I was secretly hoping for a solution based on existing tools.

Comment: yes, actually I was aware of those problems: but it's not clear how to overcome them. library(lambda) it's the best so far, but it poses some efficiency problems. I would follow instead the practical, admittedly dumb, route to specialize the 'function selector'

Comment: It is perfectly fine as it is; I can pretty much plug in a specialized version of this predicate into my program if I wanted to. You are right however that it is not exactly a "library" predicate quite yet.

Comment: Is there a reason why `State` has only two arguments? It should have three. The last being an always uninstantiated variable