# Prolog - formulate query that finds highest value within a finite amount of atoms?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I had an atom name and age pair:

```
person(bob,42).
person(jeff,12).
person(adam,23).
...
```

And I wanted to find through a query (not predicate) the youngest person.

How would I make such a query?

Comment: See [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317069/collect-all-minimum-solutions-from-a-backtrackable-predicate). By the way, what is the difference between a query and a predicate? If you just take the body of a predicate, it would be the query, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate a multi-part query with a universal quantifier, like this:

```
person(X,AgeX), forall(person(Y,AgeY), X=Y;AgeX<AgeY).
```

Essentially, this query says that `X` must be such that for each known `person` `Y` in the database it should either be the same person (`X=Y` part) or the other person must be older (`AgeX<AgeY` part)

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/9hYDdt)

Answer (score 0):

library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) solves such task, and much more... try

```
?- aggregate(min(Age,Person), person(Person,Age), R).
R = min(12, jeff).
```