# How to show only one result in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Data:

```
%flight(FID, Start, Destination, Company, Seats).
%------------------------------------------------------
flight(1, 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Lufthansa', 210).
flight(2, 'Frankfurt', 'Dubai', 'Lufthansa', 400).
flight(3, 'Rome', 'Barcelona', 'Eurowings', 350).
```

I want to know all companies that, that have flights with over 200 seats. But each company should be returned only once.

I tried:

```
q1(Company) :- flight(_, _, _, Company, S), S > 200.
```

But this returns lufthansa twice. I tried:

```
q1(Company) :- flight(_, _, _, Company, S), S > 200,!.
```

But this exited after first return of Lufthansa. I think I have to wrap the condition in a sub query:

```
q1(Company) :- flight(_, _, _, Company, S), q12(S).
q12(S) :- flight(_, _, _, _, S), S > 200,!.
```

But this exited after the first return, too. Any idea how I can return a company that matches only once using cut?

FID is the primary key and I am only allowed to use . , + < > <= >=

Comment: First, remove the `!/0`: It destroys the intended meaning of your program. Then collect all companies using `setof/3` like this: `?- setof(Company, q1(Company), Cs).` This gives you a sorted list without duplicates. If you want, you can enumerate the companies for example with `?- setof(C, q1(C), Cs), member(C, Cs).`

Comment: @mat I am not allowed to use setof, just ", . ! \+ < > <= >="

Comment: This is a weird requirement. Can you at least use `sort/2`? Otherwise you need to do a weird trick in the spirit of an SQL left join or something similar.

Comment: @Boris can you show me the weird trick?

Comment: I would have to think about it a bit. You can try to look for inspiration on the SQL tag :) or maybe someone has a ready answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here are the unique IDs. Your original question is:

> Which companies have flights with over 200 seats?

The query is obvious:

```
?- flight(_,_,_,C,S), S > 200.
C = 'Lufthansa',
S = 210 ;
C = 'Lufthansa',
S = 400 ;
C = 'Eurowings',
S = 350.
```

Now, because the IDs are unique, there is going to be a flight within the group with the same company and seats > 200 which has the highest (or lowest) ID. So, you could re-formulate your question as:

> Which flights have over 200 seats and the highest ID within the group of flights from the same company?

or, to make if a bit more close to the way that we can pose the query in Prolog,

> Given a flight with an ID, Company, and Seats, the Seats must be more than 200, and there must be no other flight from the same company with a higher ID.

```
?- flight(ID,_,_,C,S), S > 200, \+ ( flight(IDX,_,_,C,_), IDX > ID ).
ID = 2,
C = 'Lufthansa',
S = 400 ;
ID = 3,
C = 'Eurowings',
S = 350.
```

If you put this query in a predicate you can avoid reporting the ID and the actual number of seats.

By the way, this approach is a courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32881005/1812457) to a somewhat related question (shameless self-promotion). I really can't remember where I got the idea: I am certain I didn't come up with it myself. If anyone can find a good reference here on Stackoverflow or elsewhere please comment.

Comment: Thank you that brought me on the right track. BTW I found another solution that seems correct using the cut operator. I put it in my question.

Comment: @artworkadシ Are you sure you need that cut? What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comments, one way to do this is to use `setof/3` to obtain a sorted list of results **without duplicates**, for example:

```
?- setof(C, q1(C), Cs).
```

This is a **recommended** way to remove redundant solutions. You can enumerate such solutions for example with:

```
?- setof(C, q1(C), Cs), member(C, Cs).
```

*Viewer discretion is advised for the remainder...*

---

There are also several ways to solve this subject to brain-damaged conditions that an unskilled instructor may impose on you. For example, here is an inefficient and highly non-idiomatic way to obtain *all companies* that occur in your database *without* using `setof/3`:

```
companies(Cs) :-
    companies_([], Cs).

companies_(Cs0, Cs) :-
    (   flight(_, _, _, C, _),
        \+ memberchk(C, Cs0) ->
        companies_([C|Cs0], Cs)
    ;   Cs0 = Cs
    ).
```

I don't have the stomach to carry this further, so I just end with the hint for you: You only need to insert one goal to solve your task. I hope your teacher is happy with this "solution".

Comment: This uses `memberchk/2`, which is probably also not "allowed" :) but see the other answer for an alternative approach.

Comment: Everything in this version can be easily expressed using only the shown primitives. For example, `memberchk/2` and if-then-else can be expressed with `!/0`. These are all examples of logic *hacking*, not logic *programming*, so I do not want to show even more in this direction.

Comment: Why `memberchk/2` anyway?

Comment: I can't even... read `member/2` in combination with `(\+)/1`. Better use `if_/3`.